# Framework Phalcon. Admin folder does not work with Nginx

Tags: nginx, phalcon

Two PHP Phalcons are installed on the website:

1. /home/srv/http/example.com
2. /home/srv/http/example.com/admin

Part of nginx.conf:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name example.com;
root /home/srv/http/example.com/public;
index index.php;

access_log off;
error_log /var/log/nginx/example.com_error.log;

location / {
    root /home/srv/http/example.com/public;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?_url=$uri&$args;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /home/srv/http/example.com/public$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}

location /admin {
    root /home/srv/http/example.com/admin/public;
}

location ~ /admin/.+\.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /home/srv/http/example.com/admin/public$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
}
```

Previously, the apache was installed. And website and admin folder worked.

And now I replaced apache by nginx.

Website http://example.com work. But http://example.com/admin does not work, error 404.

Tell me please, what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing try files directive:

`try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?_url=$uri&$args;`

Comment: I add this, and now:
if I opening second engine /home/srv/http/example.com/admin, then first engine (/home/srv/http/example.com) show 404 error.